# Whats the 35mm focal length equivalent of an iPhone 5s?

Tags: camera, iphone

It seems a bit wide, my guess is about 25mm (35mm equiv) or so. A Google search didn't find anything useful.

Also, any info on usable ISO ranges?

Comment: Is there a problem to solve or just curiosity.

Comment: @Buscar웃  No problem. I just frame and move my feet (foot zoom) based on lenses angle of view. I was trying to shoot a pic of the most recent full moon and it seemed so small in my pic. You need to know your tools to be able to use them better. My real photo taking was with a 35mm Elan 7, and I happen to think of focal lengths in 35mm equivs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great study of iPhone camera in this article.

[How does the iPhone hold up against a serious camera?](http://www.theverge.com/2014/8/22/6055591/iphone-vs-pro-camera)

Comment: Uhm no, it's 18mm on a 1.6 crop factor, so the 35mm equiv would be 28mm, close to what you guessed.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my math @HampusNilsson, been too long since i did the math to separate focal-length and crop factor.